# how do I initialize a 3D array with two 2D array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have two array as follows:

```
a=np.vstack([np.loadtxt(path, dtype='float') for path in glob.iglob(r'E:/PostDoc/720/*.txt')])
b=np.vstack([np.loadtxt(path, dtype='float') for path in glob.iglob(r'E:/PostDoc/1080/*.txt')])
```

the `a` and `b` are two arrays with size `(640,6)`
now I define a 3D array as follows:

```
c = [[[0 for col in range(6)]for row in range(len(psnr_bitrate_1080))] for x in range(2)]
```

and I want to put a and b into c and for this, I use the following code:

```
c[:][:][0]=a
c[:][:][1]=b
```

but it does nothing and all values in `c` are still zero and it does not replace the values in `c` with `a` and `b`. do you know what is the problem? the rows and columns in `c` are lists while `a` and `b` are arrays. I try to make a 3D array with values of `a` and `b`. I do not know why it can not do correctly. please tell me how can I do this. Thanks.

Comment: What is `[:]` doing?  Not your intention; actually doing?  Why not `[:,:,0]`?

Comment: yes, right. because I am a beginner in python, I am not very familiar with syntax. by doing this it works. I use this
c=np.zeros((len(a),2,6))
c[:,0,:] = a
c[:,1,:] = b
 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "stack" two 2-D arrays, then the most intuitive method is
to use *dstack*:

```
c = np.dstack((a, b))
```

This way you don't even need to create any empty array before.

But if you want to stack your both source arrays "along another axis"
(as I see from your comment), run e.g.:

```
c2 = np.swapaxes(c, 1, 2)
```

Then `c2[:,0,:]` will return your first source array.